# AS3 AIR - "list / count" dictory contents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, directory

Using AS3 Air for Android, What code can I use to list all or count the files from a chosen directory on local machine? In this case I am using Air For Android.

Then I would like to put them in an array

I am willing to give 50 pts for this answer. As you can see for my rep it's a lot but this question is HUGE for me. I would like it if possible if we don't use a Class Package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code outputs a list of files and directories contained in the user's desktop directory.

```
import flash.filesystem.File;

var desktop:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("images");
var files:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 trace(files[i].nativePath); // gets the path of the files
 trace(files[i].name);// gets the name
 /// PUT ARRAY CODE HERE to add each "files[i].name" into an array for later use.

}
```

Comment: but how can I access the files in a different folder for example in the red folder of my application?

Comment: if platform does not define standard locations for desktop, documents, or user directories, File.documentsDirectory, File.desktopDirectory, and File.userDirectory can reference the same directory.

you can try this:
var prefsFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;

for more information http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html

Comment: Do you have skype? I really need help with this asap.

Answer (score 6):

You can recurse through directories by checking if each File in the directory listing is a directory. The following function will return the count of all files recursively (excluding directories).

```
function recursiveDirectoryListing( directory:File ):int
{
     var count:int = 0;
     if (directory.isDirectory) 
     {
         var files:Array = directory.getDirectoryListing();
         for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++)
         {
             if (files[i].isDirectory)
             {
                 count += recursiveDirectoryListing( files[i] );
             }
             else
             {
                 trace("file found: " + files[i].nativePath );
                 count += 1;
             }
         }
     }
     return count;
}
```

Then you can just call this function on whatever location you require to list:

```
recursiveDirectoryListing( File.applicationStorageDirectory );
```